# Choosing a sequence of functions to approximate from below or above

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $X\subset \Bbb R^n$ is contained in a compact set. Denote $C(X,\Bbb R)$ the collection of continuous functions from $X$ to $\Bbb R$ with the supremum norm. Suppose $A\subset C(X,\Bbb R)$ is a dense subalgebra and $f\in C(X,\Bbb R)$ is a function.

It is clearly possible to pick a sequence of functions $f_n\in A$ such that $f_n\to f$ uniformly (that's what density in the supremum norm means, after all). Is it also possible to choose sequences $g_n,h_n\in A$ such that $g_n\geq f \geq h_n$ pointwise and $g_n,h_n$ both converge to $f$ uniformly?

I think this should be obviously true, but I am bad at functional analysis and don't trust my intuition without outside confirmation. An attempt at a proof would be something like saying "the collection of functions $g$ such that $g\geq f$ at all points forms a set with nonempty interior with $f$ as a limit point, thus $A$ is also dense in the space of such $g$, and therefore a sequence $g_n$ with the requested property may be chosen". Is there anything wrong with this attempt at a proof?

Comment: How about $g_n=h_n=f$?

Comment: $f$ need not be in $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all $n\in \mathbb N$ we can find $g_n\in A$ s.t. $||(f+1/n)-g_n||_\infty < 1/n$.

Then $g_n\geq f$, for all $n$ and $$||f-g_n||_\infty\leq||f-(f+1/n)||_\infty+||(f+1/n)-g_n||_\infty \leq 2/n \rightarrow 0,$$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, so that $g_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly.

You can find $h_n$ in the same way.

Comment: This is a neat solution. Thank you for your answer.